Does Dapr support reading messages from an Azure Service Bus topic's subscription using peek API of Azure Service Bus
I am using the Azure Service Bus as my message broker for publisher and subscriber to publish and consume messages. I want to add abstraction by introducing Dapr, so that change in the message broker does not require reaction from publisher and subscriber. There is a need to read messages from the service bus using Peek APIs of Azure Service Bus so that messages are not deleted, does Dapr support the peeking of the messages from Service Bus using the Peek APIs. If yes please share me the documentation for the same, else let me know how i can achieve the peeking of the service bus topic subscripion using dapr
Thanks,
SuvraJyoti

No, to my knowledge, this isn't supported in Dapr. The messages will be read out from Service Bus to Dapr where they'll be pushed to your client app until successfully processed (per the Dapr resiliency policy you have in place for the component).
